# Error:Execution failed for task ':baseCommon:processDebugResources'

Tags: android

```
Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
Warning:android-apt plugin is incompatible with future version of Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.
Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.

Failed to parse XML resource file '/Users/xx/kotlinCode/xx/xx/baseCommon/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml'
```

This project can run on Android studio 2.3, but I take him to run on Android studio 3.0 find this mistake, the combined error is refers to the resources repetition?

Comment: post your values.xml file

Comment: How much, I'm sorry, but this merger value. The XML content of more than twenty thousand lines, I can't provide. Is there a good way for duplicates.

Comment: try clean Project, and look for faulty characters

Comment: Error of android studio 3.0 to only those above, I can't locate the error produced in (a file, merge the content of the files is too much, too much suffering.Please see the complete wrong information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is problem with your values.xml.
Check you values.xml within res folder properly or post your file.

Comment: Thank you, has been solved. Although I don't know where is the problem, but I git clone, no problem. Thank you for your answer.